# Laravel - Where do you store your own interface?

Tags: php, laravel, interface, architecture

I want to implement a custom interface for a Laravel service. In which place in the Laravel folder structure would it be best to store the implementation?

Comment: how about a folder in `app` named `Interfaces`? ... you can put things where ever you want as long as they get autoloaded and you namespace and name them correctly

Comment: @lagbox  Hey :-)! I already knew that. I thought there might be a pattern for best case or it might depend on the model. But if there are no guidelines here, then it really doesn't matter. The main thing is that it makes sense.

Comment: just saying if you can't think of a better place or you don't have things broken down into related pieces, something as general as this would work ... i prefer to have things grouped a lil more so there are many places where interfaces would exist depending on what they are for

Comment: this is a very opinionated question though ... but an example: if you have an interface that is for Models then why not have an `Interfaces` folder in the same folder as the models, now they are grouped by what they relate to

Comment: @lagbox Do you really think so? I think it's a fair question and not opinionated. But you have already answered the question well. Basically, it depends on the use case. Thank you!

Comment: the answers will be opinionated because people have different opinions and there is no right answer ... not saying you can't talk about it  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it doesn't matter where you create the corresponding interface. Everyone has to decide for themselves. If you need an interface for several areas (facade, controller, helper) then it might make sense to store the interface in the Facades folder.

Another possibility would be to create a folder Interfaces under app/ and store all interfaces there. As @lagbox had already suggested.

**Conclusion:** It always depends on the case and how you like it.